# WPF - How to persist current content when setting the content property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm facing a problem where by setting the content property of my window I obviously remove pre-existing content. On all windows I have a dockpanel that I use to pop up help contextual help to the user but this is lost when I set the content property of the window. Therefore I will only see the content for the control I've added and pressing F1 does nothing as the dockpanel does not exist. I don't want to add this dockpanel to every control  as it's poor code-reuse so what can I do to keep the dockpanel on the window and add content without overwriting original content of the window?

This is the code where I set the content of the window.

```
private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Window window = new ResizeableWindow()
        {
            Title = "Help",
            Content = new Controls.Help(),
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize

        };

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

This is code for my Help control it's just a document viewer to read an xps document, this is used by the dockpanel.

```
public partial class Help : UserControl
{
    public Help()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string appPath = "path";

        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(appPath, FileAccess.Read);

        var docx = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

        HelpDocViewer.Document = docx;
    }
}
```

This is the xaml of my ResizableWindow containing the Dockpanel

```
<Window x:Class="Controls.ResizeableWindow"           
        KeyDown="HelpKeyListen">   

    <Grid>
        <DockPanel x:Name="HelpPanel">

        </DockPanel>

    </Grid>       

</Window>
```

Here is the code for the resizeable window

```
public ResizeableWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HelpKeyListen(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F1)
        {
            var HelpControl = new Help();
            DockPanel.SetDock(HelpControl, Dock.Right);
            HelpPanel.Children.Insert(0, HelpControl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A few lines of code, showing your current approach would be good. It sounds like your basic approach has some problems but its hard to tell just from your description.

Comment: Don't change the `Content` of the `Window`.  Make a user control with your footer (or whatever control) on it, and a main `ContentArea`.  Add one of those to your form, and change the `Content` on *that*.

Comment: Also, you should *seriously consider* looking in the to MVVM pattern for WPF.  It will make things so much easier on you in the WPF world.

Comment: @grek40 I've added some examples, please let me know if there is more needed

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'd appreciate if you had any links or resources I could look into, I acknowledge that this is off topic so if this can be discussed somewhere else I'd be more than inclined

Comment: I don't see the rumored `DockPanel` anywhere in your code. With *code* I also mean relevant XAML, not only C# code.

Comment: @grek40 Sorry I didn't include it before as there isn't really much happening in the xaml I've added it anyway as well as the code for the resizeable window where it is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Placeholders inside the `DockPanel` instead of replacing the window content:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="HelpPanel">
    <ContentControl x:Name="HelpContent" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Then assign the contents of the contentcontrols as needed

```
private void HelpKeyListen(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F1)
    {
        HelpContent.Content = new Help();
    }
}
```

Possibly create a new dependency property in `ResizeableWindow` if you want to provide main content from the outside. Lets say you add a dependency property (visual studio code snipped `propdp`) named `MainContent`, then you can bind it as follows:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="HelpPanel">
    <ContentControl x:Name="HelpContent" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainContentPlaceholder" Content="{Binding MainContent,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AnchestorType=Window}}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The more appropriate option would be to replace the `MainContentPlaceholder` by some more WPF/MVVM friendly way to display your contents, but thats out of scope for the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm going to attempt to set the main content placeholder through my ribbon which has the buttons for settings, about and help. Within their btn_click events is where I'm going to set the main content.